# Avoid the "downloaded from internet" warning on mac os with a signed app

Tags: macos, qt, software-distribution

I have developed a qt mac app (not using xcode, soi do not have any xcode project) that will be distributed outside the app store.
I have successfully signed it with my developer ID certificate and if i use the following commands:

```
 spctl --assess MyAppBundle.app
```

and

```
codesign -d -vvvvvv MyAppBundle.app
```

I get fine results.
The problem is that if i download it from internet (e.g. DropBox) i get the warning "the file was downloaded from internet are you sure you want to open it"
Is there a way to avoid this warning? from what i gathered from the forum it should be possible.

Btw please note that the application passes the GateKeeper on the target computer so the actual signing seems to be working and being accepted (Gatekeeper is on default configuration: mac store and identified developers)